# Does this store the objects as an array? parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, parse-platform

I wonder if my code fetches an array in parse.com and adds it correctly to my NSMutableArray.

In ViewdidLoad:

```
self.alreadySharedWith = [NSMutableArray array];
//detailId contains the current posts objectId.
PFQuery *currentPostSharedWith = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Posts"];
[currentPostSharedWith getObjectInBackgroundWithId:detailId block:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
    self.alreadySharedWith = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:object[@"sharedWithUsers"], nil];
    NSLog(@"These are already shared: %@", self.alreadySharedWith);
}];
```

What this does is:
Gets all user's objectId where the current user's post has been shared with. (Current user can share a post with other users)

MY NSLog displays this:

> These are already shared: (
>           (
>           Vf5zOl2DiR,
>           LMiQK016A5,
>           2O906caJgJ
>       )
>   )

But when i try check whether or not Vf5zOl2DiR exists in my alreadySharedWith, i get no result. why is that so?

How i check the array for a object.

```
- (void)checkArray:(id)sender{
if ([self.alreadySharedWith containsObject:@"Vf5zOl2DiR"]) {
    NSLog(@"Found it!");
}

}
```

My log doesn't display anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're putting an array inside an array when you populate `self.alreadySharedWith`.  Maybe try changing (in `viewDidLoad`)

```
self.alreadySharedWith = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:object[@"sharedWithUsers"], nil];
```

to

```
self.alreadySharedWith = (NSMutableArray *)object[@"sharedWithUsers"];
```

Comment: I get this error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM objectId]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c394e40'

Comment: So `alreadySharedWith` contains an array then. I think you're putting an array inside an array. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Now a new error occurs: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectId]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x787b86d0'

Comment: OK then. Got it. Go back to your original checkArray code :-)

Comment: Works like never before! ;) Thanks a lot!